# JQuery - Use the value from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use the value from a function in an if statement. I have a form where I was using return false in my script but I need changed it to preventDefault.

```
<form id="percentageBiz" method="post">
<input type="text" id="sum1">
<input type="text" id="sum2">
<input type="submit" onclick="return" value="Get Total">
</form>
<div id="display"></div>​

<script>
$('#percentageBiz').submit(function(e) {
    var a = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum1"].value;
    var b = document.forms["percentageBiz"]["sum2"].value;
    var display=document.getElementById("display")
    display.innerHTML=parseInt(a,10)+parseInt(b,10);
    e.preventDefault();
});
if (display < 100) {
    $("#display").addClass("notequal");
}
</script>
```

Comment: try preventDefault at the very top.

Comment: I added preventDefault to the very top do I now add return display; to the end of the function? I tried it and I still can't seem to retrieve the value of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#percentageBiz').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $display = $("#display", this);
    var a = $("#sum1", this).val();
    var b = $("#sum2", this).val();
    var sum = +a + +b;

    $display.text( sum );

    if ( sum < 100 ) {
        $display.addClass("notequal");
    }
});
```

Comment: The above didn't seem to work. Do you still need parseInt of the variables a and b?